# How to populate a DropDownList from a SQL database using linq and only select Distinct Values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class that gets data from a database using linq and then another class that populates the retrieved data from the column into a DropDownBox. The type of data i am retrieving from the database is integers.

The Scores Column has the following values
1
1
2
3
4
1
2
2

When the DropDownBox is being populated i need it to populate the scores but only populate distinct()

I dont get any errors when doing it but the distinct is not working

here is my linq code that gets the data

```
public static IEnumerable<RiskPriorityScore> GetRiskPriorityScores()
    {
        var Scores = (from s in db.RiskPriorityScores
                      orderby s.Score
                      select s).Distinct().ToList();

        return Scores;

    }
```

The data still gets populated but i still get duplicates.

This is the code im using to bind my data into the DropDownBox

```
protected void cboRiskPriorityScore_ItemsRequested(object sender, RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        cboRiskPriorityScore.DataSource = iThNkPOCO.Models.RiskPriorityScore.GetRiskPriorityScores();
        cboRiskPriorityScore.DataBind();
    }
```

I have Modified my code accordingly But when the application is running and i click on the DropDownbox i get this error

```
Object of type System.Int32 does not have a Score property.
```

Comment: `The type of data i am retrieving from the database is integers`.  It doesn't look like that to me.  Your returning an `IEnumerable<RiskPriorityScore>`.

Comment: Do you have additional fields in RiskPriorityScore that are different? You may want to make a projection, rather than just selecting the object directly.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a list of `RiskPriorityScore`. If those contain any other property then `Distinct()` would not give you what you want. Limit your selection to only the value you want to put in the dropdown. Something like this:

```
public static List<int> GetRiskPriorityScores()
{
    var Scores = (from s in db.RiskPriorityScores
                  orderby s.Score
                  select s.Score).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Comment: i have tried that aswel but then i cant return my Scores value. because i get an error saying that i cannot implicitly convert it.

sorry i am trying to teach myself and i am still new to this.

Comment: how would i go about sorting out this error

Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<RiskPriorityScore>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: What you want your method to return is a list of integers, not list of `RiskPriorityScore` objects. That is what the query (as it is in my answer) returns, so you need to update the signature of your method. I updated my answer to include this as well.

Comment: I have modified my Code i keep getting this error 

Object of type System.Int32 does not have a Score property.

Comment: Your dropdown is setup to expect `RiskPriorityScore`. Since you changed `GetRiskPriorityScore` to return list of integers, you should change the dropdown as well.